# Will this timer code work for calling Python function every X seconds?

Tags: python-3.8

I have a Python thread, and in it, I attempt to call a function, wait X seconds after it finishes, then repeats indefinitely (runs as a Windows service).

I am using the code below. Based on the code below, since I am incrementing "count" every minute, theoretically, is there a case where this could "overflow" if it runs for a long time (like if I lowered it down to every 2 seconds or something very small)?

Is this method overkill if all I need to do is wait till the function finishes and then do it again after approximately (doesn't have to be precise) X seconds?

Code:

```
def g_tick():
    t = time.time()
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        logging.debug(f"Count is: {count}")
        yield max(t + count*60 - time.time(), 0)  # 1 Minute Intervals (300/60 secs)
g = g_tick()
while True:
    try:
        processor_work()  # this function does work and returns when complete
    except Exception as e:
        log_msg = f"An exception occurred while processing tickets due to: {e}"
        logging.exception(log_msg)

    time.sleep(next(g))
```

Comment: So your goal is to have the sleep time be dynamic so that the function call source starts approximately ever 60 seconds? Is there a reason you need that complexity, rather than just setting a 60 second sleep after each iteration?

Comment: No reason. Reviewing some old code, and thinking a simple sleep() would be sufficient for my needs now. Basically, I don't care how long the function takes, but when it returns, I just want it to "sleep" for approximately X seconds, then do it again.

Comment: Yup, then `time.sleep(60)` should work just fine!